# Dynamically typed generic type based on the optional parameter

Tags: typescript

I want to create a function that gets an optional `errorCallback` parameter. If the consumer of this function doesn't provide a callback I want to use the default. This function needs be strongly typed and use the return type of the consumer's custom `errorCallback`'s return type if its defined otherwise use my custom error handler's return type.

here is the code:

```
export enum ErrorType {
    VALIDATION_ERROR,
    API_ERROR,
    UNKNOWN_ERROR,
    UNAUTHORIZED
}

type MockZodType ={}

type MockResponseError = {}

export type ServiceError<TSchema extends MockZodType> =
    | {
            type: ErrorType.VALIDATION_ERROR;
            message: string;
            status: number;
            data: TSchema;
            originalError: MockResponseError;
      }
    | {
            type: ErrorType.API_ERROR;
            message: string;
            status: number;
            data: unknown;
            originalError: MockResponseError;
      }
    | {
            type: ErrorType.UNKNOWN_ERROR;
            message: string;
            status: number;
            data: unknown;
            originalError: unknown;
      }
    | {
            type: ErrorType.UNAUTHORIZED;
            message: string;
            status: number;
            data: unknown;
            preventDefaultHandler: boolean;
            originalError: MockResponseError;
      };

export type ServiceCallOptions<
    TServiceCallReturn extends Promise<unknown>,
    TSchema extends MockZodType = never,
    TErrorCallbackReturn extends Promise<unknown> = Promise<ServiceError<TSchema>>
> = {
    serviceCall: () => TServiceCallReturn;
    errorSchema?: TSchema;
    errorCallback?: (e: ServiceError<TSchema>) => TErrorCallbackReturn;
};

export async function callService<
    TServiceCallReturn extends Promise<unknown>,
    TSchema extends MockZodType = never,
    TErrorCallbackReturn  extends Promise<unknown> = Promise<ServiceError<TSchema>>
>({
    serviceCall,
    errorSchema,
    errorCallback = async (e)=> {
        if (e.type === ErrorType.UNAUTHORIZED && !e.preventDefaultHandler) {
            // some custom default handler;
        }
        return e; 
    }
}: ServiceCallOptions<TServiceCallReturn, TSchema, TErrorCallbackReturn>) {
    // some logic
}
```

the error comes from `errorCallback` default parameter value when it says:

```
Type '(e: ServiceError<TSchema>) => Promise<ServiceError<TSchema>>' is not assignable to type '(e: ServiceError<TSchema>) => TErrorCallbackReturn'.
  Type 'Promise<ServiceError<TSchema>>' is not assignable to type 'TErrorCallbackReturn'.
    'Promise<ServiceError<TSchema>>' is assignable to the constraint of type 'TErrorCallbackReturn', but 'TErrorCallbackReturn' could be instantiated with a different subtype of constraint 'Promise<unknown>'.
```

I don't want to use overloads. Why wouldn't this just work?

here is the [ts playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/FAUwHgDg9gTgLgAhAOwK4FsEFEY1gFQE8IQEBvYASADUBBAGQEkARW-RgeQDkB9LAJX4d+AGiq0ACoz6DhYygFUuAaS4cA6rwFDRVJbQX4AEsMYAtLM2ABfYMDjFSAWSgBjANZmoAEyIkEALxktvaOCC4e-CAAztDI0SA4eDCB5CHg0PAIDv4AyiAwAG4Alq6JuLAAPPi5rgAWIOgAhkhgcCje0eFunj5+IAB8gVQAPuRUlJQ5IABc2BUw-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-ELJB0EeKJCCMWcBFLiSJHAs0AysQE7EQWuMnIiAcG7NYk4ZDOCBNNEhDIK4CBVkKrhbmiCCuGuSllHulAcYRkE8ZeP63shD5PnhGHIO++7iS0CG-kOvSAf4wHIKBMDgVJukwfpcHYtFAU4cFL7+m+qR5c+blEapZEUVRjEErR3lrvIAmwJFjVpaeempBZVk2QpzFaZqlDFFW8kgEsc4BBN4YEGS+iGCY-DmJYCAAGTLQgACEo3FqByAVtWtb1o2zatjArEEpMAD0F3nKhpCuC8cCoQg3j7XWiB1E2LbZpMuKUCWWUgNsCBULY1hzGVkEbo58QkYeS4+QZvHICICCfiCKP4Dp7UZb5YVncA2LYldN0HAgMJQFCrg2EAA) link.

Comment: The issue here is that callers can manually specify type arguments (callers choose these and not implementers) and leave out the optional parameters, so they can ask for crazy things like [this playground link](https://tsplay.dev/WzDd2N) shows.  If you are not worried about that then you can use a type assertion as shown [here](https://tsplay.dev/mxydGW) and move on, but the error is there due to a genuine type safety hole.  Does that fully address the question? If so I'll write up an answer explaining; if not, what am I missing?

Comment: I see what could cause a problem, basically I need to force the errorCallback to be defined if the `TErrorCallback` is not `unknown` (the default value of T when we don't pass anything). And the only solution would be function overloads right?

Comment: "the only solution would be function overloads" well, you can use a type assertion as I showed if you think the issue the compiler complains about is unlikely enough to ignore.  So shall I write an answer or am I missing something about the question?

Comment: @jcalz if we go by the assumption that only and only if the callback is not defined the type is for sure going to be the default errorcallback type, then we are all set right?

Comment: @jcalz go for it! Thanks for the response that cleared it up for me >_<

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that technically the one who *calls* a [generic](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/generics.html) function specifies its type arguments, not the one who *writes* the function.  The caller might not ever intentionally do this, because the compiler can often *infer* the type arguments, but this inference is happening on behalf of the caller and not the implementer.  And while the implementer can choose [default](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-2-3.html#generic-parameter-defaults) type arguments for when the type arguments cannot be inferred, the caller always has the option of manually specifying the type arguments in any way that meets their [constraints](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/generics.html#generic-constraints).

So even though your intent is that when the caller leaves out the `errorCallback` property, the compiler will use `Promise<ServiceError<TSchema>>` as the type argument for the `TErrorCallbackReturn` type parameter, you cannot guarantee this.  A particularly unhinged caller could do something like this:

```
const f = await callService<
    Promise<string>, {}, Promise<number>
>({ serviceCall: async () => "a" });
```

Here the caller is claiming that the missing `errorCallback` property would return a `number`.  But your [default argument](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Default_parameters) `async (e) => {⋯}` doesn't do that, it returns a `ServiceError<TSchema>`.  Indeed it returns a `ServiceError<TSchema>` no matter what the `TErrorCallbackReturn` type argument is, which is why the compiler complains.  That's what

```
'Promise<ServiceError<TSchema>>' is assignable to the constraint of 
type 'TErrorCallbackReturn', but 'TErrorCallbackReturn' could be 
instantiated with a different subtype of constraint 'Promise<unknown>'
```

means.

---

So, what can you do?  [Overloads](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/functions.html#function-overloads) are one approach, so you can explicitly control the available call signatures the caller sees.  This would make it impossible for a caller to pass the third type argument unless they also pass the expected `errorCallback` property.

```
async function callService<
    TServiceCallReturn extends Promise<unknown>,
    TSchema extends MockZodType = never,
>(arg: {
    serviceCall: () => TServiceCallReturn, errorSchema?: TSchema,
    errorCallback?: never
}): Promise<void>;

async function callService<
    TServiceCallReturn extends Promise<unknown>,
    TSchema extends MockZodType = never,
    TErrorCallbackReturn extends Promise<unknown> = Promise<ServiceError<TSchema>>
>(arg: {
    serviceCall: () => TServiceCallReturn, errorSchema?: TSchema,
    errorCallback: (e: ServiceError<TSchema>) => TErrorCallbackReturn
}): Promise<void>;
```

But if you don't want to refactor much, you can just say that you don't think the bad call is likely enough to worry about, and that you [assert](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/everyday-types.html#type-assertions) that the default callback argument is of the proper type.  Possibly like this:

```
async function callService<
    TServiceCallReturn extends Promise<unknown>,
    TSchema extends MockZodType = never,
    TErrorCallbackReturn extends Promise<unknown> = Promise<ServiceError<TSchema>>
>({
    serviceCall,
    errorSchema,
    errorCallback = (async (e: ServiceError<TSchema>) => {
        if (e.type === ErrorType.UNAUTHORIZED && !e.preventDefaultHandler) {
            // some custom default handler;
        }
        return e;
    }) as (e: ServiceError<TSchema>) => TErrorCallbackReturn
}: ServiceCallOptions<TServiceCallReturn, TSchema, TErrorCallbackReturn>) { }
```

That fixes the compiler error, and as long as your assertion remains valid, everything should work as you expect.

[Playground link to code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/KYDwDg9gTgLgBMAdgVwLZwKJStAKgTzGDgG8AoASADUBBAGQEkARG3BgeQDkB9DAJT7s+AGko0ACg14ChoigFVOAaU7sA6j36CRlRTXm4AEkIYAtDEzIBfMmRiFiAWQgBjANamIAEwJE4AXlIbOwc4Z3c+YABnSEQo4CwcKACg21BIWDh7PwBlYCgANwBLFwTsaAAeXByXAAtgVABDBBAYJC8osNcPb19gAD4AygAfUkoKbOAALkxyqD6AOlpGFjYuaW0AbnHUaKjGgHNpuCiYKCLEA+2KClPGmGQomZRUACN864ove8aZ8J6fA5PtAigcLo0ADaJaB-bqRGIQOJlJLXGwUUbkG6TGbQ+YOBYSKRaISfXZRfZHGanc6XT53B5POAvd5QT7fGC-ODIRBuRAQADuiGB5zBiEhuNhEWisXiuNRIzGWIcOLmi0UKnUmhkfFJe0Ox2pFyu43pj2eaBZbJ+M25vIFQvGINF4rmNp5fMF8vRiomytmSTVnH0RhM5iYuvJ+qpZyNdI5DPNbw+43ZnNtHodNzAUGABSQMCYwAAZo1kBCYIZGogvBD8jNXhAILWq8LQeCoa6ulKEUi5ZQrNsyOloPBJnA8oUSsAAMKQiHsMAwIqIqIVSjVfLFUqziEQyIPKCIFptaudcQ4VBFeIVdP2-pyap1BrNUAnjpdgF9FKIXP5B+4ncIVeRopQPI9X3aM8LyvYAb3dO8UnPCBL2vCct2RSpH3qJp+n6MhBkCTF4knbc5xmAAKABKAJBg3EiZznfdkEPa58iSGpsMaAB+GYsOfVi5kA4D3B4uByOONCp1xKoOOffpqP8WiALnYS3CYljrEHYdMkaKJ8EQFw4CLbkXCXRE4BcOdJNKNcKDo9DAPU8DWkguAkJQ2Db0Fe911kppj1c-5PEBPxAh-PMoH-QSVJAtTgDAgLTzc6Dry8xACOS5CYIqayMKgGSnxwvD+nIojNynQC5DY6A-MaKrot3VSUnI3T9MM8SZly6S+JwhTBkxCgiiLMTgAWMd-Am-08HxPQDGMPgzAsOAADJlrgABCUbs1-RAC2LUty0rataygaiBooAB6C6TmQ4gXEeGBkLgLx9rLeBairGtkxuNEKBzBLgFRajdJGzrytKbravkmi4FwZTGtipzrDB+jAIXMy4hk8GGN3JzhFh2r8bhhqgMR+LmPSs7KH+imEBJ1TNjgK64AqABaVm4AAKweuAwWKS44GaD7juIcyYFqK9rFsMhWoMoyTIxiyrOxgBGWz7IqxjycPRL33c7K0p8uzat1zogt6UIwt-SL8JaqADhmMrUbIsS+oJ7HHO1xB8eqqBatEnq6soX2hNi0TwvyaxKJmfXrwKCAii8fpB1lwzjIMxXLN3XK1d8j2tYBlyktjzz4O8h8TYgpLzZC4grYiqKklD0DaarvWUtLu1vMQjucuxyHCsaXDbcae3HcoYiHJdqiYY10jca9n25n93jCeD+nYooiT+7mArOOhxTYfh0mW8PKOY97+PE+T2xU-ljPlyPLOIRz9Xcs9wu3ygrLUrL9KK8HqbD8wUvz1z-LbJ2U9dz1XYoPGB0Bm5uGanfcSbsBpDRGmNS2k1cSBmDPNRaTAVprU2gsbaeZdqFhLG9I6X1To+kutdKIt0LIPSei9ah5Y4DCzoZ8X6NMdaA37JRZG45867nRo-Vcc8cZ7kXgTOBgtED4GhuQKWMs9Jy3TqZR+RlGwzzUbYCgLgVzwGGoERo-JGhFHgM-XKtkKAlwqIaS494gj4yccyfIeEKAlRICccREIZgoLdgAIkaKEuAVhKKDmMaYpkKRLHWLMaVLIfpcEzWUKoDQGxZDPWtHAFW+MyQUmOKE0J+MnTtglIU-GppGQqyiTEygiAxoQAAGJFBAMALwVFGbM3FleOA-Iii7jgNmCAwFXgQnwC0MAEJvDEHuHAKA3Ily7FsFYIAA)

Comment: jcalz thanks for your time and answer!! Just one more question. Which approach would you choose yourself? the overload solution or the assertion solution?

Comment: Probably the assertion and only refactor to overloads if it turns out that people actually do the bad call in practice.

Comment: Is your reasoning because function overloads are hard to maintain/read? beucase I would stay away from them because of those reasons.

Comment: My reasoning is I'd do the easiest thing first (maybe even `as any`) and then fix it if it matters.  There are various reasons why overloads may be good or bad but I'm not really prepared to have this discussion here.